# Why isn't the video feed read by the web camera in python code?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

When I run my python `opencv` code, the web camera does not read a video feed. There are no any errors, but the black color output with wifi sign and loading sign i there. How  to fix that and read the video feed.  Here is my code and the output.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

print(cap.isOpened())
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
       print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
       print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

       out.write(frame)

       gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
       cv2.imshow('frame', gray)

       if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and works fine for me. Can you check if it works if you don't do any video saving related stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using one camera you can try the following:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
```

This will pick up the first webcam the system can find.
How are you overlaying the wifi/loading signs - I assume they are not part of the webcam feed?

Comment: I tried with -1, but it didn't work. Then i tried with 1, and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Strange - but glad it helped!